# How can I subtract -1 from the z-index, every time toggle is triggered?

Tags: jquery

I want to prevent it interfering with other toggles.

```
$(".button-info").click(function() {
    $("#info").fadeToggle("fast");
    $("#info").css("z-index", "-1");
});
```

Comment: Here is the official jQuery UI documentation on how to handle z-index: https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-zIndex

Answer (score 1):

You can use `css` like below.

```js
$("#info").css("z-index", function(index, val) {
  return parseInt(val, 10) - 1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own jQuery function if you want to use this combination a lot.

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.fadeToggleZ = function() {
    return this.fadeToggle("fast").css("z-index", (parseInt(this.css("z-index")) - 1));
  };
}(jQuery));

$(".button-info").click(function() {
  $("#info").fadeToggleZ();
});
```

```css
.info {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  background: red;
}

.info2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button-info">Test</button>
<div id="info" class="info">testdiv</div>
<div id="info2" class="info2">testdiv2</div>
```